# CSV moudule printing formula

Tags: excel, csv, formula

The script:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.read_csv("aapl.csv", header= 0 , encoding = 'latin-1')


print(df2)
```

result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evJFH.png)

As you can see when printing where there is CSV formula I get the formula instead of the value...
any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the column type

```
import openpyxl, csv
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.read_csv("aapl.csv", header= 0 , encoding = 'latin-1', dtype={"upper": int,"lower": int})


print(df2)
hope this will help you
```

Comment: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '=l11+m11*1.5'`